# How to configure kafka producer topic with more than one partition using Spring integration kafka

Tags: spring, spring-integration, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I read many articles but didn't found how to configure Producer which have topic with multiple partition (topic created at runtime) using Spring Integration Kafka.

I am using [github link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka) to understand and configure kafka for my application.

Kindly provide the solution for the same

One more thing, What the is use of kafkaHeader.messageKey.

**Update : Below is test code which I develop**
`    public class OutboundTests {
    @Test
    public void mytest() throws Exception{

```
    KafkaProducerContext<String, SMSNotificationVO> ctx = new KafkaProducerContext<String, SMSNotificationVO>();
    ProducerMetadata<String, SMSNotificationVO> meta = new ProducerMetadata<String, SMSNotificationVO>("sms_topic");
    meta.setValueClassType(SMSNotificationVO.class);
    meta.setKeyClassType(String.class);
    meta.setValueEncoder(new SMSObjectSerializer());

    ProducerMetadata<String, SMSNotificationVO> meta1 = new ProducerMetadata<String, SMSNotificationVO>("sms_topic_10");
    meta1.setValueClassType(SMSNotificationVO.class);
    meta1.setKeyClassType(String.class);
    meta1.setValueEncoder(new SMSObjectSerializer());
    Properties producerProperties = new Properties();
    producerProperties.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "1");//"message.send.max.retries"
    ProducerFactoryBean<String, SMSNotificationVO> producer = new ProducerFactoryBean<String, SMSNotificationVO>(meta,"192.168.1.147:9092");
    ProducerFactoryBean<String, SMSNotificationVO> producer1 = new ProducerFactoryBean<String, SMSNotificationVO>(meta1,"192.168.1.147:9092", producerProperties);


    ProducerConfiguration<String, SMSNotificationVO> p = new ProducerConfiguration<String, SMSNotificationVO>(meta, producer.getObject());
    ProducerConfiguration<String, SMSNotificationVO> p1 = new ProducerConfiguration<String, SMSNotificationVO>(meta1, producer1.getObject());

    Map<String, ProducerConfiguration<String, SMSNotificationVO>> map = new HashMap<String, ProducerConfiguration<String, SMSNotificationVO>>();
    map.put("sms_topic", p);
    map.put("sms_topic_10", p1);

    ctx.setProducerConfigurations(map);

    // java code to send message
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("Topic", "TEST MULTIPLE TOPIC : this is sms_topic_1");
    List<String> smsRecipients = new ArrayList<>();
    smsRecipients.add("9953225211");


     String message = "This Test message from junit topic sms_topic_1";
     Integer messageType =1;

    SMSNotificationVO vo = new SMSNotificationVO();
    vo.setMessage(message);
    vo.setMessageType(messageType);
    vo.setParams(params);
    vo.setSmsRecipients(smsRecipients);


    try{
     KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, SMSNotificationVO> handler = new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, SMSNotificationVO>(ctx);
     handler.setMessageKeyExpression(new LiteralExpression("sms_topic_10"));
     handler.handleMessage(MessageBuilder.withPayload(vo)
             //if i remove the below comments I will get null pointer exception
             //.setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "some key")
             //.setHeader(KafkaHeaders.PARTITION_ID, "1")
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "sms_topic_10")
                .build());

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Assert.fail("Kafka SMS Producer fail");
    }

}  
}`
```

I am getting Null pointer Exception. Below is the mention log:

```
`org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler@7b94089b]; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:84)
at dd.kafka.producer.OutboundTests.mytest(OutboundTests.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$serialize$1.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:130)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$serialize$1.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:127)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.serialize(DefaultEventHandler.scala:127)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:53)
at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)
at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ProducerConfiguration.send(ProducerConfiguration.java:70)
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaProducerContext.send(KafkaProducerContext.java:197)
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:81)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
... 24 more`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Topic isn't related to the `Producer`. You should have pre-configured Topic in advance before send or receive message to/from it.

The fact that you can create the topic at runtime using `AdminUtils.createTopic()` over the Spring Integration high-level API is just for testing convenience and should be avoided for the production.

The `KafkaHeaders.messageKey` is fully mapped to the standard Kafka `messageKey` and yes can be used to determine the target `partition` in the `topic`.

So, you definitely should go to the official Apache Kafka documentation to understand how to create topic with "multiple partition" and what to do from the `Producer` side regarding `partition` and `messageKey` parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

There few queries in my mind which is as follow:
1. messagekey is use to determined the partition in the topic(some like hashing) then how to chose that key as i want to chose key at random so that every time the message publish it goes into other partition to make use of parallelism.
2. In the link mention, `message-key-expression` and `partition-id-expression` on what bases these value is mention
3. If message-key-expression is mention then only i can use KafkaHeaders.messageKey.

Thanks

Comment: If you specify the particular `partition` on sending operation, than the `messageKey` is bypassed by the partition determination algorithm. Those expression is used exactly for the Kafka `Producer` operation. See its API. Indeed, the `KafkaHeaders.messageKey` can be used instead of `message-key-expression`.

Comment: But If you see my code, `setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "some key")`  gave null pointer exception

Comment: M-m-m. Looks like you use enough old library version. How about to upgrade to the latest `spring-integration-kafka-1.3.0` ?

Comment: Project using spring-integration-kafka-1.1.1. I will try with 1.3.0 version.

Comment: Hi After updating the jar I am getting following Warning :   NetworkClient:582 - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 106 {sms_topic_10=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}. Hence I am not able to sent messages from producer

Comment: I delete directory  /tmp/kafka-logs but still result same

Comment: I update kafka to  kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1 because after update jar i am getting exceptions So I update the same

Comment: For Kafka 0.9 Client you have to use just released Spring Integration Kafka 2.0 https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/11/spring-integration-kafka-support-2-0-0-m1-is-now-available. The previous version isn't compatible . Although Kafka Client 0.8 , and therefore SIK-1.3, works well with Kafka 0.9

Comment: Great. I will check the same

Comment: I getting the same issue : NetworkClient:582 - Error while fetching metadata with update 2.0 jar

Comment: Kindly explain the reason. So that i can find issue

Comment: And here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259069/apache-kafka-failed-to-update-metadata-java-nio-channels-closedchannelexception

Comment: M-m-m. From other hand it is just `WARN` on my side and I'm able to send message to the topic and consume them from there. That is covered by our tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108839/discussion-between-rahul-and-artem-bilan).